# Count total from column selected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve total of each column of my result. Below are my expected result and menu selection table.

Menu selection table:

[image: Menu selection table]

After query/expected result:

[image: Expected result]

The problem is I have a problem in calculating total of each column.

This is my query:

```sql
    SELECT menu_option,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='QUEUE', 1, 0)) AS Queue,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ROUTING' , 1, 0)) AS Routing,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='CALLBACK' , 1, 0)) AS Callback,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ANSWER' , 1, 0)) AS Answer
    FROM tbl_call_center_menu_selection
    GROUP BY menu_option
    UNION
    SELECT  'Total' AS c, 5 AS a, 2 AS b, 0 AS c, 0 AS d
    FROM tbl_call_center_menu_selection
```

Comment: Why hard code the total line when you could use group by with rollup? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html AND if you include sample data as text we could use that to test possible answers.

Comment: If u review my 'Menu Selection' table, i did the row as each of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using subquery

```
SELECT menu_option,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='QUEUE', 1, 0)) AS Queue,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ROUTING' , 1, 0)) AS Routing,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='CALLBACK' , 1, 0)) AS Callback,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ANSWER' , 1, 0)) AS Answer
    FROM tbl_call_center_menu_selection
    GROUP BY menu_option
    UNION
    SELECT  'Total' , sum(Queue), sum(Routing), sum(Callback), sum(Answer)
    FROM 
    (
        select menu_option,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='QUEUE', 1, 0)) AS Queue,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ROUTING' , 1, 0)) AS Routing,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='CALLBACK' , 1, 0)) AS Callback,
        SUM(IF(callStatus='ANSWER' , 1, 0)) AS Answer
    FROM tbl_call_center_menu_selection group by menu_option
    )A
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you ^^